# Objects not displaying inline on my mobile device

Tags: html, css, iphone

My 3 objects within the same class will not seem to align so that they are distributed evenly when viewed on my mobile device (iPhone). It works fine when I use the web dev tool on chrome.
I have opened the webpage in both Safari and Chrome on my iPhone and yet it continues to display in a block (stacked horizontally).
You can view this live here at [thairapyexeter.co.uk/about.html](http://thairapyexeter.co.uk/about.html)

HTML:

```
<div class="aboutuscalltoaction">
  <div id="directionsaction"><img src="directionsaction.png"></div>
  <div id="callaction"><img src="callaction.png"></div>
  <div id="emailaction"><img src="emailaction.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.aboutuscalltoaction{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items: center;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
}

}
#callaction{
    position: relative;
}
#directionsaction{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `display: flex` and also a float?

Comment: Also `display:fixed` is not a thing.

Comment: I used the flex as it seemed to work with my browser...

Comment: My mistake the position was actually relative